# Knockout.js AJAX POST response is [object Object] or {}

Tags: knockout.js

So far I have the following:

```
<h1>jQuery post form data using .post() method</h1> 
<form id='userForm'>
    <div><input type='text' name='phone' placeholder='phone' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>
<div id='response'></div>
```

and

```
var viewmodel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.phone= ko.observable();

  self.submit = function(){
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");
        $.post('/echo/html/', ko.toJSON(self), function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            $('#response').html("fail!");
        });
        return false;
    });
```

How can I display results in response?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyno8c65/9/

Comment: You are not supposed to use jQuery to modify the DOM in a Knockout application. You can use it to do Ajax, for everything else you have to use Knockout bindings. **In other words**, please work through the [truly excellent tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) and read at least half of the documentation, because you have not done any of that so far.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm trying to alert, or console.log the returned value (phone) from the ajax call. As the way I have it, it returns object Object or {} .

Comment: *Please* go through the tutorial before you do anything else, you really are missing extremely basic stuff about knockout. Also, do not use `alert()`. Use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="response">
   <!-- ko if: isLoading() -->
   <b>Loading response</b>
   <!-- /ko -->

   <!-- ko if: !isLoading() -->
   <!-- ko text: response -->
   <!-- /ko -->

   <!-- ko if: hasFailed() -->
   <span>Failed</span>
   <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
self.response = ko.observable();
self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
self.hasFailed = ko.observable(false);

self.submit = function() {
    self.isLoading(true);
    self.hasFailed(false);

    $.post('/echo/html/', ko.toJSON(self), function(data) {
        self.response(data);
        self.isLoading(false);
        self.hasFailed(false);
    }).fail(function() {
        self.response(null);
        self.isLoading(false);
        self.hasFailed(true);
    });
}
```